# Corners not connected in paperjs shapes

Tags: paperjs

I am trying to draw some shapes using `paperjs` using `CompoundPath`. But the corners of the shapes are not intersecting and there is some space between the segments. For example, if I try to draw a triangle as follows:

```
var point0 = new Point(448, 217);
var point1 = new Point(110, 565);
var point2 = new Point(785, 565);


console.log(point0);
var path = new CompoundPath({
    children: [
        new Path.Line(point0, point1),
        new Path.Line(point1, point2),
        new Path.Line(point2, point0)
    ]
});
path.strokeWidth = 15;
path.strokeColor = "black";
```

The corners of this triangle are not connected. Here is the Sketch link for the same: [Sketch Link](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/fZGxDoIwEIZfpekESUMoESEYJ1cHEwcHylCgUULtmVJ1ML67BaoRBoamubuv/31JX1jxq8AZPrbCVBdMcAV1Xz+4RjdolAnRFinxRIe+8FarlKCIJv6GaaZ+EJ1AlIYExet4BkUTKEnjP+h7KlAdSBFIOHvj+r8Qbi4uYgfXG9xVfbAt7zU8tvaNrLVQGcrHBjPDNosE+0YJl0ecsU8WKOqoaJGKHBX6I1T013sU7mWDzmhoxampB3Eazyc7kKDthOFS8qpleGM/oNSCt0Nuh7O8eH8A).

How I can make connected corners in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `CompoundPath` to connect some lines, you can build a `Path` including them.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/ZZDBDoIwDIZfpdlFSDg4AmJGPPkCJh48AIcBjZDBZrapB8K7yzQQ0Z7a7/+SNh2I5D0SRs4CbdWQgFSqdvODa7ipVtotHEDiE05u8KJoH0BIEz/NdS4Xia4kSrcBxLv4RwpXUrKPv6RF5LaZtan1BhfAVAavPUprGGQzcvU5MfhD9B+FMymWzFitBF7a2jYMaPzDj6pTmsGm7HglNktYdcpgzcDqOzo2+un0tlIjF+89hrCsGF8=) demonstrating the solution.

```
var point0 = new Point(448, 217);
var point1 = new Point(110, 565);
var point2 = new Point(785, 565);

var path = new Path({
    segments: [
        point0,
        point1,
        point2
    ],
    strokeWidth: 15,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    closed: true
});
```